# jQuery - check if .noconflict has been triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading a jQuery script dynamically into random pages.
Sometimes they support jQuery, sometimes they have other libraries and sometimes they don't have any library at all..

I need to support all cases, therefore, first I check if jQuery has loaded.
Case not, I load jQuery dynamically into the page using .noconflict (to avoid conflicts in case there are other libraries there, daahhh) and then just continue with my script.

Case it's already been loaded, I need to know if the page has triggered the .noconflict function or not.
Why ? it's simple.
Let's say a random page have both Prototype and jQuery (happens, yes).
The webmaster trigger the .noconflict mode for the jQuery, to avoid conflicts with it.
After that, I trigger my script, and check if jq has been loaded (yes).
And then, I have to know weather to use $() or jQuery() methods, since if I'll continue using $() I might access the Prototype handler, 
And I don't want that.

Comment: Always use `jQuery()`, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

[`.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) only removes the `$` object and not the `jQuery` object. (Except if you add `true` as first parameter.

So you can always use `jQuery()`

Comment: Yes, I can always use jQuery(), but since I'm loading the jQuery into the page, I have to know weather to use .noconflict or not before that.

Comment: @Gal Why can't you always use .noconflict?

Comment: I believe I eventually can. The situation is that I'm injecting jQuery into an already running page, I have no idea if jQuery is loaded, or any other library. It might have 2 libraries in it, with noConflict already triggered (or not), and I just wish to continue with the same typing as the original page did. Coming to think about it again, might be useless.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else said, you should just always default to using the full jQuery object instead of the alias. If it's a quantity-of-typing issue, use $ and then find-replace in your text editor before pushing to live.

...But if you absolutely, positively MUST do this the ridiculous way, it's simple:

```
​if​ ($ == jQuery) { alert("YAY"); }​​​​​​
```

Here's an example I cooked up on JSFiddle using jQuery 1.8 and a separately-loaded MooTools 1.4.5: http://jsfiddle.net/fL9rk/2/

Run it once, then unload the external MooTools and try again.

Don't say we didn't warn you.

Comment: Yes, I MUST use this ridiculous way :)

Comment: My spirit shudders for fear of the the evil that you help to spread upon our hapless world. However, if I have helped you bring umbral dark across the intertron, do consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Patience my young coder, patience is that you must use to receive those credits which you seek for.

Comment: @GalWeissman - It has been over 7 years. Has he been patient enough?

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
//Insert your javascript code here

});
```

and all of your jQuery code will be in these braces and will never conflict with other prototypes.

Comment: Let's say there's a page running prototype, and then I inject jQuery into it. If I don't run any jQuery function, will it conflict with the prototype that's already there.?

Comment: No it will not, when u are outside of these braces you are in scope of that prototype and within these braces you are within jQuery scope.

Comment: that's going to make the inner function to run on dom ready.
it's equivalent to:

    jQuery.ready(function($){
    
    });

which is probably not what he wants.